# MIN() MAX() on a column created using window function

Tags: sql, window-functions

I created a column called custom_rank using window function. Is there a way to get a min and max of that specific column per userid? I'm basically trying to get a min and max weight of a given user based within their enrollment period.

```
select top 1000 
  c.weight, c.units, 
  rank() over (partition by uuid, enrolled_on order by enrolled_on desc, input_date asc) as "weight_rank"
  from tableA a
join tableB b
  on (b.member_no = a.member_no)
join tableC c
  on (c.userId = b.uuid)
where input_date >= enrolled_on and input_date < cancel_date
```

Comment: mysql doesn't have window functions. what's your dbms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CTE and then get max/min of each user.

```
with mm as
(
    select top 1000 
      c.weight, c.units, c.userId
      rank() over (partition by uuid, enrolled_on order by enrolled_on desc, input_date asc) as "weight_rank"
      from tableA a
    join tableB b
      on (b.member_no = a.member_no)
    join tableC c
      on (c.userId = b.uuid)
    where input_date >= enrolled_on and input_date < cancel_date
)
select   userId, min(weight_rank), max(weight_rank)
from     mm
group by userId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `max()` and `min()` as window functions:

```
with cte as (
      select c.weight, c.units, uuid,
             rank() over (partition by uuid, enrolled_on
                          order by enrolled_on desc, input_date asc) as weight_rank
      from tableA a join
           tableB b
           on b.member_no = a.member_no join
           tableC c
           on c.userId = b.uuid
      where input_date >= enrolled_on and input_date < cancel_date
     )
select top 1000 cte.*,
       max(weighted_rank) over (partition by uuid) as max_weightedrank_user,
       min(weighted_rank) over (partition by uuid) as min_weightedrank_user,
from cte;
```